# using Maven setting.xml to pass build arguments to fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, docker, maven-docker-plugin

we are using fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin to build dockers in our application.
because we are sitting behind a corporate firewall we need to setup a proxy for our build.

as part of our docker files, we defined ARG HTTPS_PROXY.

now to build our docker we need to pass the proxy argument using the mvn command line as:

```
mvn clean install -Ddocker.buildArg.http_proxy=<proxy> 
-Ddocker.buildArg.https_proxy=<proxy>
```

I am looking for a way to set up this configuration in the maven setting xml.
to make it easier.

any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892111/maven-cannot-connect-to-network-inside-docker/45892749#45892749

Comment: Do you not have a repository manager in your network ? Apart from that are you building docker images insider a docker image ?

Comment: Hi The answer of your question is already made here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy