# Corporate proxy error downloading Jars related to Delta Lake from pyspark packages

Tags: python, maven, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I am trying to set up a local dev environment in docker with pyspark and delta lake.

I have gone through the compatibility of versions between delta lake and spark [here](https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html).

I have the following in my Pipfile (using pipenv)

```
pyspark = {version = "==3.2.2", index = "artifactory-pypi"}
delta-spark={version= "==2.0.0", index = "artifactory-pypi"}
pytest = {version = "==7.1.2", index = "artifactory-pypi"}
pytest-cov ={version= "==3.0.0", index = "artifactory-pypi"}
...other packages
```

The artifactory-pypi is a mirror of pypi.

I have gone through [this](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#python) and trying to setup a python project for unit testing. The code already has this

```
_builder = (
        SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]")
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
        .config(
            "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog",
            "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog",
        )
    )
    spark: SparkSession = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(_builder).getOrCreate()
```

When I try to run my unit tests using pytest, it always fails at

```
configure_spark_with_delta_pip(_builder).getOrCreate()
```

with an error that it can't connect to maven repo to download

```
delta-core_2.12;2.0.0
```

I am not very well versed with Java, but I have done some digging to see that within

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/jars/
```

folder there is a `ivy2.jar` file which apparently has info on what jars are needed and it tries to reach out to maven coordinates . This connection is refused as I am behind a corporate proxy.
I have tried setting

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY=proxyurl
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=proxyurl
```

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892111/maven-cannot-connect-to-network-inside-docker), Maven does not honor http_proxy env variable and the answer suggested that the OP set those in some configuration files. But in there the OP was using a Maven image and thus had those conf files already. I do not have such files or folders as I am just using a python image. It is just that those python packages (pyspark)  behind the scenes go and download jars.

I have also tried looking at [spark runtime env variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/configuration.html#runtime-environment)  especially `spark.jars.repositories` to see if I could set them in my `docker-compose.yml` but event that didn't work.

How can I get this to work? Can someone suggest either

1. If it is possible to let this download go via a org artifactory? If so, where do I suggest it. e.g. for all my python packages, I am using a pypi mirror.
2. I can also download the jars manually, but how and where do I copy them and what environment variables to set to make it work e.g. PATH ?

Btw, here is the full stack trace

```
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
Ivy Default Cache set to: /root/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /root/.ivy2/jars
io.delta#delta-core_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-63bca6fa-4932-4c6d-b13f-4a339629fc26;1.0
        confs: [default]
:: resolution report :: resolve 84422ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
        :: modules in use:
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.0.0

        ==== local-m2-cache: tried

          file:/root/.m2/repository/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.0.0/delta-core_2.12-2.0.0.pom

          -- artifact io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.0.0!delta-core_2.12.jar:

          file:/root/.m2/repository/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.0.0/delta-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar

        ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

          /root/.ivy2/local/io.delta/delta-core_2.12/2.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml

          -- artifact io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.0.0!delta-core_2.12.jar:

          /root/.ivy2/local/io.delta/delta-core_2.12/2.0.0/jars/delta-core_2.12.jar

        ==== central: tried

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.0.0/delta-core_2.12-2.0.0.pom

          -- artifact io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.0.0!delta-core_2.12.jar:

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.0.0/delta-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar

        ==== spark-packages: tried

          https://repos.spark-packages.org/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.0.0/delta-core_2.12-2.0.0.pom

          -- artifact io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.0.0!delta-core_2.12.jar:

          https://repos.spark-packages.org/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.0.0/delta-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.0.0: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
        Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.0.0/delta-core_2.12-2.0.0.pom (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused))

        Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.0.0/delta-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused))

        Server access error at url https://repos.spark-packages.org/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.0.0/delta-core_2.12-2.0.0.pom (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused))

        Server access error at url https://repos.spark-packages.org/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.0.0/delta-core_2.12-2.0.0.jar (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused))


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: io.delta#delta-core_2.12;2.0.0: not found]
```

Any questions and I can try to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the S.O community, I have been able to solve this- basically by combining information from multiple S.O posts and answers.

So, this is how:

1. As I mentioned in my question, I already had the env variables for proxy set

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY=proxyurl
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=proxyurl
```

2. Then as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676395/how-to-resolve-external-packages-with-spark-shell-when-behind-a-corporate-proxy), especially the answer by Thomas Decaux.
3. Then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025924/is-there-a-spark-defaults-conf-when-installed-with-pip-install-pyspark) about where to find the spark-defaults.config file when you install pyspark through pip.
4. Then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286436/running-pyspark-after-pip-install-pyspark) about setting the relevant environment variables.

So, combining all of them, this was how I did it in my dockerfile

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY=proxyurl
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=proxyurl
WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark
RUN mkdir conf
WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/conf
RUN echo "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true" > spark-defaults.conf
ENV SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark
ENV SPARK_PYTHON=python3

Other app specific stuffs
```